# How to extract keys as arrays from an array of objects?

Tags: lodash

I need to extract, from this array

```
const mylist = [
            {
               "key": "",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "IT",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
```

an array of the values of `key`:

```
["", "IT"]
```

Today I use a simplistic approach

```
finalList = []
_.forEach(myList, function (element) {
  finalList.push(element.key)
})
```

but I saw that `lodash` has several methods which are *almost* the ones for my case: `_.zip`/`_.unzip`, `_.fromPairs`/`_.toPairs` and `_.zipObject`

Is there a way to simplify this code based on a `lodash` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily without lodash by using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the keys to an array:

```js
const mylist = [{"key":"","doc_count":3},{"key":"IT","doc_count":1}];

const result = mylist.map(({ key }) => key);

console.log(result);
```

If you already have lodash in your project you can use [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map):

```js
const mylist = [{"key":"","doc_count":3},{"key":"IT","doc_count":1}];

const result = _.map(mylist, 'key');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```